# List of possible values for particular path variable in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Consider three REST resources:

```
/persons/id/{id}
/persons/code/{code}
/persons/email/{email}
```

I want to make one method in a `Spring MVC` controller to handle these requests:

```
@RequestMapping("/persons/{searchField}/{searchValue}")
public Person search(@PathVariable field, @PathVariable value) {
...
}
```

The question: is there any elegant way to restrict `searchField`'s variable list of values **on the annotation level** except just by checking them in the method `search`?

```
switch (field) {
  case "id": ...
  case "code": ...
  ...
  default: // not found exception??
}
```

Comment: Don't. Define three methods with the appropriate path each.

Comment: The elegant way is to define a method for each acceptable value of searchField, as noted by Sotirios above

Comment: how about @RequestMapping("/persons) and use RequestParam instead of PathVariable?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I actually can do it easily, see my answer :-D

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It can be easily done using regular expressions in the mapping:

```
@RequestMapping("/persons/{searchField:id|code|email}/{searchValue}")
```

Comment: Worth to mention, with such mapping the swagger (if someone uses it) will generate a request `METHOD /persons/{searchField}` (with no info about possible values that'll be matched), so for generating documentation we would need to add additional `@Schema` parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a enum as type for your @PathVariable that will make Spring to limit the accepeted request values to the values of the enum